# How to cancel an AFdownloadrequestoperation and not retain previous progress(delete the temporary file) iOS

Tags: ios, download, afnetworking

I am downloading a file from server.
I am able to download the file Successfully.
But Whenever I cancel the download request(in between) operation and restarts the download.
Download starts from the previous progress (not from zero).
but I want to restart downloading from zero.

Setting  `operation.deleteTempFileOnCancel = YES;` is also not helping

No file is created at the target path given , when I cancel the download in between

```
operation.tempPath is returning null (not able to delete temporary file)
```

I am using the following code

```
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.downloadUrl]];
     operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];
     operation.deleteTempFileOnCancel = YES;


            // download operation progressive block
            [operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile)
             {
                 // calculate current download progress

                 }
             }];

            // download operation completion block
            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
             {


             } 

            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                 // operation failed


             }];

           [operation start];
```

I want to start the download from zero if Download is cancelled in between and then started again . I am using iOS 7

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm fighting with this now too.

Comment: Which version of `AFNetworking` and `AFDownloadRequestOperation` are you using?

Comment: I use this code but downloaded file not showing in document folder pls reply asap

Answer (score 1):

Well I just found a workaround to this. I will post it here in case someone else will have the same issue.

After this line you could check if the tempPath is actually created

```
operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];
NSLog("%@", operation.tempPath);
```

Then add that path to a dictionary

```
NSString *tempPath = _operation.tempPath;
[self.tempPathDict setObject:tempPath forKey:your_key];
```

And when you stop the operation you call this code

```
NSString *tempPath = [self.tempPathDict objectForKey:your_key];
// Cancel the operation you want
[operation cancel];
// Remove the tempFile 
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tempPath error:&error];
// And last remove the path from the dictionary
[self.tempPathDict removeObjectForKey:your_key];
```

Comment: Will try this and will let you know :)

Comment: I saw there is a `deleteTempFileOnCancel` property there in `AFDownloadRequestOperation`, but it seems it does not trigger the deletion when I did `[operation cancel]`, so we need to manually delete it.